# Material and select multiple with formly

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-formly

i search a way  to create a select multiple (typescript way  and not JSON way)

formly don't seem to like **multiple: true**

```
const jobName: FormlyFieldConfig = initMultipleSelect(
     'Job type',
     {
        multiple: true,
        type: InputDataAttribut.InputType.select,
        label: 'Job type',
        options: jobTypeList
    });   


export function initMultipleSelect(key: string, props: FormlyFieldProps): FormlyFieldConfig {
    return {
        className: 'select-selector',
        key: `${key}`,
        type: 'select',
        props: props
    };
  };
```